# Почему не воспроизводится .gif?

Tags: python, многопоточность, gui, pyqt, qmovie

Гифка не проигрывается. А просто закрывается окно и открывается другое.

Получаю ошибку:

> QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread

По задумке должна отыграться гифка, а потом открывается другое окно. 
Вот гифка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnwgE.jpg

```
...

def nextbutton(self):
    background_gif = QMovie('images\\background.gif')
    self.ui.background.setMovie(background_gif)
    # background_gif.start()
    def sleeper():
        background_gif.start()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = sleeper)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
    self.close()
    self.window = timeofperson()
    self.window.show()

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import os
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

    started  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()   
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def started_gif(self):

        self.started.emit()        

        def finished_gif():    
            self.finished.emit()

        t = threading.Timer(5.0, finished_gif)
        t.start()      


class GifDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(GifDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet("QDialog {background-color:black; color:white }")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            text="Пожалуйста, подождите, \nотыгрывается гифка...",
            font=QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, weight=QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        )

        self.label1.setStyleSheet("color: green;")   

        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) #@

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def show_gif(self):
        movie = QtGui.QMovie(
            "D:/_Qt/img/spir.gif",                
            parent=self
        )
        self.label2.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        self.show()

class TimeOfPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('TimeOfPerson окно')
        self.resize(600, 500)
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('TimeOfPerson окно', self)


class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        nextButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton( text="Next",
                                          clicked=self.next_Button )
        cancelButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel", clicked=self.close)

        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        hbox.addWidget(nextButton)
        hbox.addWidget(cancelButton)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def next_Button(self):

        self.worker = Worker()

        self.gif_dialog = GifDialog(self)

        self.worker.started.connect(self.gif_dialog.show_gif)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.w_close)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.worker.started_gif) 
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()        

    def w_close(self): 
        self.gif_dialog.close()  
        self.hide()

        self.timeOfPerson = TimeOfPerson()
        self.timeOfPerson.show()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.setWindowTitle('Первое окно')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сейчас дам ссылку на другой вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/951511/qobjectstarttimer-timers-cannot-be-started-from-another-thread

Comment: Другой вопрос - это другой ответ.  А что с этим вопросом? Что вам не подходит в моем примере?