# QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread!

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5

```
class informationwindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = informationwindows()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Исторический фотошоп")
        # Здесь записываем события нажатий на кнопку
        self.ui.background.setPixmap(QPixmap('images\\background.png'))
        self.ui.nextbutton.clicked.connect(self.nextbutton)


#Кнопка "ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ"
    def nextbutton(self):
        background_gif = QMovie('images\\background.gif')
        self.ui.background.setMovie(background_gif)
        # background_gif.start()
        def sleeper():
            background_gif.start()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = sleeper)
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
        self.close()
```

Макет

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class informationwindows(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1280, 720)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1280, 720))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1280, 720))
        self.nextbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.nextbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(99, 566, 320, 86))
        self.nextbutton.setObjectName("nextbutton")
        self.background = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1280, 720))
        self.background.setText("")
        self.background.setObjectName("background")
        self.background.raise_()
        self.nextbutton.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.nextbutton.setText(_translate("Form", "Продолжить"))
```

background.png - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtN3w.jpg

background.gif - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnwgE.jpg

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку продолжить срабатывала гифка, и только после этого закрывалось это окно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переделал метод `nextbutton` и добавил метод `gif_ended`, который вызывается при завершении анимации гифки.

```
def nextbutton(self):
    background_gif = QMovie('images\\background.gif')
    self.ui.background.setMovie(background_gif)
    background_gif.start()
    background_gif.finished.connect(self.gif_ended);

def gif_ended(self):
    self.close()
```

Документация по сигналам `QMovie`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmovie.html#signals

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class informationwindows(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1280, 720)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1280, 720))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1280, 720))
        self.nextbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.nextbutton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(99, 566, 320, 86))
        self.nextbutton.setObjectName("nextbutton")
        self.background = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.background.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1280, 720))
        self.background.setText("")
        self.background.setObjectName("background")
        self.background.raise_()
        self.nextbutton.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.nextbutton.setText(_translate("Form", "Продолжить"))


class informationwindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = informationwindows()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Исторический фотошоп")
        # Здесь записываем события нажатий на кнопку
        self.ui.background.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('images\\background.png'))
        self.ui.nextbutton.clicked.connect(self.nextbutton)


#Кнопка "ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ"
    def nextbutton(self):
        background_gif = QtGui.QMovie('background.gif') 
        self.ui.background.setMovie(background_gif)

        self.sleeper(background_gif)

    def sleeper(self, background_gif):        
        background_gif.start()
        self.ui.background.show()

        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self, timeout=self.doClose)
        self._timer.setSingleShot(True)       # срабатывает только один раз
        self._timer.start(2000)

    def doClose(self):        
        self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = informationwindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```